# Polymer 1.0: google-signin sign in still success when user revoke permissions

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using a **google-signin** element to have access to user's access scopes.
I found, if I as a user authorize my app with certain scopes, then revoke those scopes without clicking on "Sign out" button (basically the google-signin element), the google-sign results in a **onSigninSuccess event** even without the authorization.

This is weird. It should be **onSigninFailure** because the app doesn't have the corresponding scopes of authorizations from the user.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that once signed in google/the google-sigin tag itself does not check again for scopes.